# ¿Cómo imprimir una multiplicación en ensamblador X86?

Tags: ensamblador, x86

Hola este es mi código en ensamblador, como ven deseo multiplicar `8*8`, pero tengo un problema, que no sé como imprimir el `64`, en mi caso intenté dividir entre `10` e imprimirlo, pero me sale un error de `sizes`
¿cómo debo imprimir?, En que estoy fallando?.

```
section .bss
    resultado resb 1

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov ax, 8
    mov bx, 8
    mul cx

    mov eax, cx
    mov ebx, 10
    mov edx,0
    div ebx
    add eax, 48
    mov [resultado],eax


    mov rax, 1
    mov rbx, 1
    mov rsi, resultado
    mov rdx, 1
    syscall
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Convertir entero a cadena en Assembler](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/584407/convertir-entero-a-cadena-en-assembler)

Answer (score 1):

El problema en tu código es que estás utilizando registros de 16 bits para almacenar los valores de multiplicación y división, lo cual no es suficiente para el resultado de la multiplicación de 8 * 8 (que es 64) ni para el resultado de la división entre 10 (que es 6).

Para resolver este problema, necesitas usar registros de 32 bits para realizar la multiplicación y la división correctamente. Aquí te muestro cómo puedes hacerlo:

```
section .bss
    resultado resb 1

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov eax, 8      ; Colocar el primer operando en eax
    mov ebx, 8      ; Colocar el segundo operando en ebx
    mul ebx         ; Multiplicar eax por ebx (resultado en edx:eax)

    mov ecx, 10     ; Colocar el divisor en ecx
    xor edx, edx    ; Limpiar edx para la operación de división
    div ecx         ; Dividir edx:eax por ecx (cociente en eax, residuo en edx)

    add eax, '0'    ; Convertir el resultado en ascii
    mov [resultado], al ; Colocar el resultado en el buffer resultado

    ; Ahora podemos imprimir el resultado
    mov rax, 1      ; Código de la syscall para imprimir
    mov rdi, 1      ; Descriptor de archivo para stdout
    mov rsi, resultado ; Puntero al buffer que contiene el resultado
    mov rdx, 1      ; Longitud del buffer (1 byte en este caso)
    syscall

    ; Salir del programa
    mov rax, 60     ; Código de la syscall para salir del programa
    xor rdi, rdi    ; Código de salida 0
    syscall
```

Con estos cambios, deberías poder multiplicar 8 * 8 y luego imprimir el resultado "64" correctamente. En este código, se utilizan registros de 32 bits para almacenar los valores, y después de la división, se convierte el resultado en un carácter ASCII para imprimirlo adecuadamente.

Comment: cuando pruebes el codigo quita los comentarios los puse para que entenideras mejor