# Convertir entero a cadena en Assembler

Tags: linux, ensamblador

No encuentro información para convertir un número entero a caracter. Es lo que se denomina función "itoa" (integer to ascii) y a ver si aquí alguien me puede ayudar. Pongo un script de ejemplo, para los que ya saben de esto verán que se explica por sí mismo:

```
.macro  print var, len
        movq  $1,               %rax
    movq  $1,           %rdi
    movq  $\var,        %rsi
    movq  $\len ,       %rdx
    syscall
.endm

.data
        num:    .quad   1234
        len_num = . -num

        msg:    .string "Show the number like an ASCII: "
        len_msg = . -msg

        nl:             .string "\n"
        len_nl = . -nl

.bss
        buffer: .skip   6

.globl _start

.text
        _start:

                movq    num,    %r8    # r8 = num pointer
                addq    $0,     %r9    # r9 = counter of digits

        .procedure:
                addq    $48,    %r8    # digit converted to ascii
                movq    %r8,    buffer  # Insert the ascii value on buffer

                cmpq    $len_num,%r9   # If counter = lenght of num
                je .final               # exit from the loop, otherwise
                        incq    %r8    # it will point to the next value 
                        incq    %r9    # & incrementing the r9 counter 
        loop .procedure

        .final:

        print msg, len_msg

        print buffer, 6

        print nl, 2

        # Exit
        movq  $60,              %rax
        movq  $0,               %rdi
        syscall
```

Poned el foco en el bucle .procedure que creo que está ahí el problema. Quizás tiene que ver que no sé convertir un dato numérico a string y poderlo desmenuzar dígito a dígito y ser convertido a ASCII. Es una suposición.

Espero que alguien encuentra la solución. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema?

Comment: La variable buffer no refleja nada después de mandarla a imprimir con print buffer 6 (nombre de variable = %rsi, longitud a imprimir = %rdx). Así que el problema es saber qué ocurre en el bucle .procedure para que buffer no ingrese nada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identifiqué algunos problemas.

- No puedes obtener la longitud de un número. Lo que hace esta línea es calcular los bytes que ocupa en memoria (8):

  ```
  len_num = . -num
  ```
- Con las siguientes líneas estás sumándole 48 al número y moviendo sus 8 bytes a `buffer`:

  ```
   add    $48,    %r8
   mov    %r8,    buffer
  ```

  El número es 1234 así que el resultado es 1282.

  En un procesador little-endian `buffer` tendrá los bytes D2400000.

Para convertir un número en una cadena numérica necesitas obtener sus dígitos y sumarle '0' (48) a cada uno. Para eso se puede dividir el número por 10 hasta llegar a 0. El resto de cada división es el dígito.

Primero cuentas los dígitos:

```
_start:
    movq num, %rax # numero
    movq $10, %r9  # divisor
    movq $0, %r10  # digitos

_numLength:
    # digitos++
    incq %r10

    # n /= 10
    xorq %rdx, %rdx
    divq %r9

    # while (n > 0)
    cmpq $0, %rax
    ja _numLength
```

Así se vería en C, te ayudará a entenderlo:

```
int digitos = 0;
do {
    numero /= 10;
    digitos++;
} while (numero > 0);
```

Entonces lees los dígitos guardándolos de atrás para adelante, ya que con `n % 10` se leen las unidades.

En C:

```
for (char* it = buffer + digitos - 1; it >= buffer; it--){
    *it = n % 10 + '0';
    n /= 10;
}
```

En ensamblador:

```
_numConvert:
    # it--
    decq %rcx

    # n /= 10
    xorq %rdx, %rdx
    divq %r9

    # caracter = '0' + (n % 10)
    addb $48, %dl
    # *it = caracter
    movb %dl, (%rcx)

    # it >= buffer
    cmpq $buffer, %rcx
    ja _numConvert
```

Por si a caso, de forma simple, la [división](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/div.html) involucra los registros **rdx** y **rax**. **rax** es el dividendo y el operando de **div** es el divisor. Es necesario establecer previamente **rdx** en 0 (una manera de hacerlo es con `xor %rdx, %rdx`).

Una vez hecha la división, el cociente se encuentra en **rax** y el resto en **rdx**.

---

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##nVRdT4MwFH3nV9woRo2MjGmMLtmDMT4s8W2vJkuhlVVL2WiH7NfP2xZGQX2RF@g59@Pcj0KUYkUqDhOijse4IFlVAmwrLjXUpIpAMBkAPkVZ7wDCJDIHuKhI8ytMuQe/2QiIqgGKIS1KXQh1UBkRIoiZpEUQxJRoYgm5L@bmHe/2hOI7md3eBS6Qyh2jNCrN4Wy1Kb9Ab5jxSVkFgn8yIBKeVs/L5RzOrBfmXaMnLCCGCX64WFLYUBCnB80gmaKCVClLpfv3d1bNMc0n38LtzIKU51yrDnxA81yUqYC10qTSeNSs0dbSIXP7fSofBUa2fQDnrdqhQZhMjcEj0pTXXJVj3tLJ1PJGiitjjbFemcz1pk/IZbaztsEJaspqZ1sf9QNwVdUGf@wts2LbJSO93QfxMgVDZSZTNBBlnnNYMQ2m4IWpF0hOuPyjJz@8MuPlxgA3XehhOxxr/LNeJqG002PxU4ueS1kzfyiU2R5lzX96hCMQcLOAy@mlnzqF8O4BnanwLJdSYWKwW4a3q2zL8qtJjUsEV0bO9XgSv9bZjqOtqndxFzjEJY8gbPd@kvzgu5jjmbW0RDFh4pf70nA96v/9eEW8LW3/Bv4tPx6/AQ), o también ver el [código generado por el compilador](https://godbolt.org/z/7YbYsf5qd) a partir del código en C. Sin optimizaciones hace algunas operaciones innecesarias, pero con optimizaciones hace cosas raras que dificultan la lectura.

Comment: Hola Mateo: todo ha ido bien y quiero destacar que tu respuesta ha sido excelente y muy didáctica. Aún hay mucho por aprender con ella y la miraré con calma.

Solo una pregunta más: En tu código ¿hay alguna razón para que el tamaño de bytes a reservar en la pila (para 'buffer') sea 10?

Comment: @Ferran le dí espacio para 32 dígitos para tener buen espacio. Al menos en decimal, un número de 64 bits usaría hasta 19 dígitos por lo que sobran 12 bytes. No sé a cual 10 te refieres.

Comment: Nada, nada, lo del 10 ni caso; un lapsus. Te respondí a las 7 de la mañana y aún debía estar algo dormido. Discúlpame. Todo está claro y meridiano.